# loop over multiple list of dictionaries using ansible

Tags: json, list, loops, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to loop over a following variable structure using ansible and what I want is to loop over each subnet.
For *subnets-1* I want to get network, cidr, vlan
similarly loop other keys *subnets-2*, *subnets-3*

> **flavor.json**

```
{
  "subnets-1": [
    {
      "network": "test1",
      "cidr": 21,
      "vlan": 123
    },
    {
      "network": "test2",
      "cidr": 22,
      "vlan": 234
    }
  ],
  "subnets-2": [
    {
      "network": "test3",
      "cidr": 43,
      "vlan": 879
    },
    {
      "network": "test4",
      "cidr": 21,
      "vlan": "12fsd"
    },
    {
      "network": "test5",
      "cidr": "22sdf",
      "vlan": "234sdfd"
    }
  ],
  "subnets-3": [
    {
      "network": "test44",
      "cidr": "fg",
      "vlan": "dsfsd"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried something like below using with_dict

> **playbook.yml (ansible 2.9.7)**

```
---
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no  
  tasks:
  - name: lookup yaml
    set_fact:
      flavors: "{{ lookup('file','flavor.json') | from_json }}"
  - name: json out
    debug:
      msg: "{{ flavors }}"
  - name: check keys
    shell: |
      echo "s_name = {{ item.network }}"
      echo "s_cidr = {{ item.cidr }}"
      echo "s_vlan = {{ item.vlan }}"
    with_dict:
      "{{ flavors }}"
```

This is the error I get when playbook was executed

**Error:**

```
fatal: [192.168.110.128]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'network'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/fla.yml': line 19, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: check keys\n    ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: Each `item` is a key-value pair, and the value is an array.  Show us what output you want.

Comment: @Jack
yes Jack each item again is a k,v pair 
I want to output loop through the keys and for each key show following

s_name = test1
s_cidr = 21
s_vlan = 123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*include_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task). It's simpler compared to *lookup* and *from_yaml*, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: flavor.json
        name: flavors
```

gives

```yaml
  flavors:
    subnets-1:
    - {cidr: 21, network: test1, vlan: 123}
    - {cidr: 22, network: test2, vlan: 234}
    subnets-2:
    - {cidr: 43, network: test3, vlan: 879}
    - {cidr: 21, network: test4, vlan: 12fsd}
    - {cidr: 22sdf, network: test5, vlan: 234sdfd}
    subnets-3:
    - {cidr: fg, network: test44, vlan: dsfsd}
```

Then [convert the dictionary to list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) and iterate [*with_subelements*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }}
              {{ item.1.network }}
              {{ item.1.cidr }}
              {{ item.1.vlan }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ flavors|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: subnets-1 test1 21 123
  msg: subnets-1 test2 22 234
  msg: subnets-2 test3 43 879
  msg: subnets-2 test4 21 12fsd
  msg: subnets-2 test5 22sdf 234sdfd
  msg: subnets-3 test44 fg dsfsd
```

Comment: Thank U @Vladimir
It does help but can you please explain what - value does in with_subelements loop ?

Comment: Take a look at ``- debug: msg="{{ flavors|dict2items }}"``

Comment: Yes. Understood.! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does not do nested loops well.  In this case, you know you have a maximum of three array elements.  So you can loop like this:

```
- name: loop over flavors
  debug:
    msg: "{{ flavors[item.0][item.1] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ flavors }}"
    - [ 0, 1, 2 ]
  when: flavors[item.0][item.1] is defined
```

Which results in something like this:

```
TASK [loop over flavors] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-1', 0]) => {
    "msg": {
        "cidr": 21,
        "network": "test1",
        "vlan": 123
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-1', 1]) => {
    "msg": {
        "cidr": 22,
        "network": "test2",
        "vlan": 234
    }
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-1', 2]) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-2', 0]) => {
    "msg": {
        "cidr": 43,
        "network": "test3",
        "vlan": 879
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-2', 1]) => {
    "msg": {
        "cidr": 21,
        "network": "test4",
        "vlan": "12fsd"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-2', 2]) => {
    "msg": {
        "cidr": "22sdf",
        "network": "test5",
        "vlan": "234sdfd"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-3', 0]) => {
    "msg": {
        "cidr": "fg",
        "network": "test44",
        "vlan": "dsfsd"
    }
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-3', 1]) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=['subnets-3', 2])
```